# How to reload data from a specific NSMutableArray into a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, uitableview

Hi I'm using a web service that returns a JSON document. In that document are several objects, each one containing a value for "STATE" (among others like "ADDRESS", "DISTANCE",etc). This "STATE" value can be either "ARCHIVED" or "ACTIVE". What I want to do is to load the objects with "ARCHIVED" value of "STATE" into the archivedProcessTV and the others to activeProcessTV.

I managed to fill both mutable arrays with the desired data but when the TableViews reload, they reload all the objects into the cells.

Here is what I'm doing on `connectionDidFinishLoading`:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

NSLog(@"Entrou no connectionDidFinishLoading");

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

process = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil] objectForKey:@"GetGesturbeDataJsonResult"];

NSInteger i = 0;

archived = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
active = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSObject *array1 in process) {
    while (i <= process.count) {
    if([[[process objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"STATE" ] isEqualToString:@"ARCHIVED"])
        {
            [archived addObject:[process objectAtIndex:i]];
            i++;
        }else
            [active addObject:[process objectAtIndex:i]];
            i++;
    }
}

[activeProcessTV reloadData];
[archivedProcessTV reloadData];
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"a cell"];
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"a cell"];

cell.textLabel.text = [[process objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"DISTANCE"];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show your table view data source method implementations

Comment: @Wain I don't know if you meant what I just added to the question. (sorry for the ignorance)

Comment: Do you merge somewhere those two arrays (active and archived) and mix all the values together ?

Comment: @Justafinger no, i don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have 2 problems:

1. `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` does not check which table view is asking for data
2. You don't use your specific array contents to populate the table views, you use `[[process objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"DISTANCE"];` which contains all data

So, at the start of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you should have an `if` statement which checks the `atableView` parameter and decides which array to use. Then, edit the line which updates the cell text to use that array.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *sourceArray;

    if (atableView == self.activeProcessTV) {
        sourceArray = self.active;
    } else {
        sourceArray = self.archived;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"a cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"a cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"DISTANCE"];

    return cell;
}
```

---

Aside: this code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"a cell"];
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"a cell"];
```

needs to be changed to:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"a cell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"a cell"];
}
```

as currently you're always creating a new cell even if you did get a reusable one back...

Comment: I've edited the code like you suggested and it gives me this error:     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: Wain, you need to initialize the source array. Otherwise it will always nil??

Comment: @HussainShabbir sourceArray points to self.active or self.archived and is never null unless the two latter are not initialized.

Comment: Thank you @Wain your help was precious!

Answer (score 0):

In-spite of using sourcearray just pass like that below and check:-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"a cell"];
if (cell == nil){
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"a cell"];
}
if ( atableView ==self.activeProcessTV) {
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.activeProcessTV objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"DISTANCE"];
}
else{
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.archived objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"DISTANCE"];
}
return cell;
}
```

**Note: Pass the correct array count inside numberOfRowsInSection method of UITableView.**

Comment: the problem remains, it gives the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: Did you check your array is not nil??

Comment: What you are returning in this numberOfRowsInSectionn method of UITableView??

Comment: I've corrected it, it was returning the process.count instead of the active.count or archived.count accordingly! Thanks!